# How to log into Azure App with a user from a different tenant?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-management-api

I have created an app on my Active Directory through 'App Registrations (Preview) and am using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL.js) to log into the app. The app will be making API calls with the 'user_impersonation' scope, so I have enabled that in the app.

I also would like users that have not been added to the tenant to be able to log in and use the app, so I set the 'signInAudence' to 'AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount'. If I understand this correctly, this should allow any account, regardless of the tenant it is a member of to sign in.

However, when I make the login request to the app with an account that is not a user in the apps tenant, I get the error message: 'Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'MyTenant' and cannot access the application 'MyApplicationID' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.'

I am using the following javascript to make the call:

```
var applicationConfig = {
    clientID: "MYCLIENTID",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANTID",
    graphScopes: ["https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"],
    graphEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
};

var headers = new Headers();

var userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, tokenReceivedCallback);

function clicked(){
    console.log('clicked');
    userAgentApplication.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (idToken) {
        userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
            var bearer = "Bearer " + accessToken;
            headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
            var options = {
                method: "GET",
                headers: headers
            };
            var endpoint = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01";
            fetch(endpoint, options).then(function (response) {
                var body = response.body;
            });
        }, function (error) {
        });
    }, function (error) {
        //login failure
    });
}
```

Is there anything I am missing to get this to work or am I misunderstanding the 'AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount' setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified your authority as: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANTID`.

You need to specify it as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0`, this allows any account to log in.

This allows users from any Azure AD tenant to log in.
Note we cannot use common since you want to access Azure APIs.

If you specify the tenant id, only users from that tenant should be able to log in.

Comment: Testing the 'common' authority, I found that if I use the 'user.read' scope, everything works, except my access token is not valid for user_impersonation requests. Using the 'user_impersonation' scope, personal accounts say 'your email or password is incorrect' when logging in. Work account is able to login with an error: "Using application 'auth_test' is currently not supported for your organization mydomain.com because it is in an unmanaged state. An administrator needs to claim ownership of the company by DNS validation of mydomain.com before the application auth_test can be provisioned."

Comment: Ohhh you are accessing Azure APIs! Then you can't use common, you have to use "organizations" instead of common. This is because personal accounts cannot have access to an Azure sub, they have to be members of an Azure AD.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user in the different tenants to log in your application, you must register a multi-tenant application in Azure AD. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-a-new-application-using-the-azure-portal). Meanwhile, you need to specify your authority as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`.